# Binding is not working in Angular2 template

Tags: data-binding, typescript, angular

errorType is not showing when calling with `Alert.showAlert("success","someMsg");`from another `Component` but it's working when initializing at the declaration of errorType itself.

component :

```
 import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'alert-component',
        templateUrl: 'app/alert.template.html'
    })

    export class Alert {

     public static errorType:string;
     public static messageAlrt:string;

     public static showAlert(type:string, message:string): void{
          Alert.errorType=type;
        }

    }
```

template :

```
<div id="messageAlert" >
            <strong>{{errorType}}:</strong> this is the error message at top of the page      
        </div>
```

Really apreciate your help in resolving this problem that errrorType value is not getting bound to erroType

Comment: can u share the code from where you are calling showAlert function

Answer (score 3):

It's because you use static fields. When using `{{errorType}}`, a non static property of the component is used.

I would refactor your component this way:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'alert-component',
    templateUrl: 'app/alert.template.html'
})
export class Alert {
  public errorType:string;
  public messageAlrt:string;
}
```

When you want to display your alert, I would add it dynamically:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `<div #target></div>`
})
export class SomeComponent {
  @ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target;

  showAlert(type:string, message:string) {        
    this.resolver.resolveComponent(Alert).then(
      (factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
        this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory);
        this.cmpRef.type = type;
      }
    );
  }
```

See this great Günter's answer:

- [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)